# how to get count with linq / linq2sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql, f#, sequences

```
<@[for i in linq.TrueIncidents -> i.RecTime, i.Name ] @> |> query |> Array.ofSeq
```

How can I get counts of different names ?

just `count(Name) where Name = somename...`

I think first I must select form here all Names with |> Seq.distinctBy(fun x -> x.Name)
and then make Seq.Count() different selects where Name will be one of names and then union all the selects ... really wierd way.

Or I can use it as object later with closure with int ref counters for each distincted Name...

I understand that my explanation could be some messy , so ask if you can't get it. I want to know is there any way to use Count(Name) where Name = OneOfNames inside closure or linq2sql ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't compile to verify that this works at the moment, but try the following:

```
<@ linq.TrueIncidents
   |> Seq.groupBy (fun i -> i.Name)
   |> Seq.map (fun (name, is') -> name, Seq.length is') @>
|> query
|> Map.ofSeq
```

This should give you a `Map<string, int>` of each name and its respective number of occurrences.

Comment: The operator Seq.groupBy may not be used in queries. Use Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.Query.groupNy instead, which has a different return type to the standard F# operator

Comment: but     member X.CountStatistics()= 
        linq.TrueIncidents
        |> Seq.groupBy (fun v -> v.Name)
        |> Seq.map (fun (k, vs) -> k, Seq.length vs)
        |> Array.ofSeq is solution , sadly with no sql